# Pinescript : Round of nearest 0.05 in decimal places

Tags: pine-script

I wish to round off any values to the nearest tick in decimal points.
For example if the calculated TP or SL is 101.68 it should be rounded off to 101.70
my ticker's decimals moves in 0.05 increments.

In Metatrader4 I acheived this as

```
price=NormalizeDouble(price-NormalizeDouble(MathMod(price,0.05),2),2);
```

How to achieve this in Pinescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Round to tick", overlay=true)

f_round_up_to_tick(x, mintick)=>
    mult = 1 / mintick
    value = ceil(x*mult)/mult
    
f_round_down_to_tick(x, mintick)=>
    mult = 1 / mintick
    value = floor(x*mult)/mult

var float   stopLoss = 101.68

roundedStopLos = f_round_up_to_tick(stopLoss, syminfo.mintick)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(roundedStopLos))
```

Source: [Rounding to the nearest tick in Pine Script](https://backtest-rookies.com/2020/09/12/tradingview-rounding-to-the-nearest-tick-in-pine-script/)

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this too, came to this solution before I found a better and simpler one. Just went back to add it here, for the next person in need for this.

In pinescript V5 you can now simply use:

```
math.round_to_mintick(value)
```

It just rounds value to the closest mintick value of the asset you are using

Answer (score 0):

```
x=0.0 
y=0.0 
x := 123.436 
x := x*100     // x = 12343.6 
x := round(x)  // x = 12344 
y := x % 5     // y = 4 
x := x/10      // x = 1234.4 
x := floor(x)  // x = 1234 
x := x/10      // x = 123.4 

if (y >= 3 and y < 7) // for this example it is true 
   x := x + 0.05      // x = 123.45
elif (y >= 7)
   x := x + 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks @cubesareneat this worked with some tweaking for syntax. Thanks for taking the pains.

x=0.0
y=0.0
x := 123.436
x := x*100    // x = 12343.6
x := round(x) // x = 12344
y := x % 5    // y = 4
x := x/10     // x = 1234.4
x := round(x) // x = 1234
x := x/10     // x = 123.4

if (y >= 3 and y < 7)  // for this example it is true // if it is false it was already calculated with the second call to round()
  x := x + 0.05     // x = 123.45

Comment: awesome! I updated it for the next person

Comment: sorry i mad e a mistake you need one more if and change the seccond round to floor(). if it was .06 it would round up to .1 not to .05. should work now